# define a short line as node shape

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, nodes, draw

I hope you are doing well. how can I define a short line as node shape? there are just some defined shapes like a circle or rectangle.

```
bnode/.style={shape=circle, draw=black, line width=2}
```

Comment: Hmmm... Why the circuitikz tag?

Answer (score 2):

I would use a `pic` for that. You can give special points like left, middle, and right anchor-like coordinates, and adjust its appearance with keys.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[pics/line/.style={code={%
  \tikzset{Line/.cd,#1}
  \def\pv##1{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/Line/##1}}% 
  \draw[pic actions] (-\pv{l}/2,0) coordinate (-left) -- 
    (\pv{l}/2,0) coordinate[pos=0.5] (-middle)  coordinate (-right);
    }},Line/.cd,l/.initial=1cm]
 \draw (0,0) pic(line1) {line} (4,0) pic[thick,blue,rotate=30] (line2){line={l=2cm}};
 \draw[red] (line1-middle) to[bend left] (line2-left);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Of course, you can also use `edge`s to draw lines.

If you really want to use a node, you could do

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line/.style 2 args={inner sep=0pt,append after command={
 (\tikzlastnode.west) edge[#2] (\tikzlastnode.east)},
 minimum width=#1},line/.default={1cm}{}]
 \draw (0,0) node[line](line1) {} (4,0) node[rotate=30,line={2cm}{thick,blue}] (line2){};
 \draw[red] (line1.center) to[bend left] (line2.west);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]